# VueJS: axios returns 404 Not Found error on POST request

Tags: node.js, vue.js, post, axios, http-post

**Updated and overwrite previous get methods. Now using POST**

this question might seems similar to another previous by another Stackers out there. But I'm really out of clue and almost burnt out due to this dummy mistakes. When request sent on page loading, it keeps return error as per below images:-
[image: POST Response]

I'm pretty sure I might mislooking somewhere else, but can you guys help me to figure where is the mistakes that I'm unnoticed on? Will share below the relevant codes to be used. in exact, this is VueJS.

View page

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="jumbotron">
      <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    </header>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card card-container">
        <form name="form" @submit.prevent="handleBiodata">
          <div v-if="!successful">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                name="firstname"
                :value="firstname"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                name="lastname"
                :value="lastname"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="age">Age</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                name="age"
                :value="age"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address">Address</label>
              <input
                type="textarea"
                class="form-control"
                name="address"
                :value="address"
              />
            </div>

<p><strong>Response:</strong> {{ content }}</p>

            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div
        v-if="message"
        class="alert"
        :class="successful ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger'"
      >{{message}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {biodata} from '../modules/biodata.module';

export default {
  name: 'Biodata',
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Biodata',
      submitted: false,
      successful: false,
      message: '',
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      age: 30,
      address: '',
      uid: this.$store.state.auth.user.id,
      content: '',
      sent_info: ''
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentUser() {
      return this.$store.state.auth.user;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    biodata.getBiodata(this.$store.state.auth.user).then(//this is to get the user data from the backend
      response => {
        this.content = response.data.message;
      },
      error => {
        this.content =
          (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString();
      }
    );
  }, 
  methods: {
    handleBiodata() {
      this.submitted = true;
      this.successful = true;
      this.message = 'Submitted!';
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card-container.card {
  max-width: 350px !important;
  padding: 40px 40px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 20px 25px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.profile-img-card {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  display: block;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Controller

```js
const db = require("../models");
const User = db.user_table;//user model
const { request } = require("express");

exports.infoBio = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Biodata Controller");
};

exports.getBio = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findByPk(req.body.request_body.user.id).then(user => {
  //User.findByPk(1).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: "User Not found." });
    } else{
      res.status(200).send({ 
        message: user.username
      });
     }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
  });
};
```

Module

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import {API_URL, authHeader, /*userState,*/ API_CALL_TIMEOUT} from './helper.module.js'

class Biodata {

  getInfoBio() {
    return axios.get(API_URL + '/biodata/infobio', { headers: authHeader() });
  }  

  getBiodata(user) {
    let auth_header = authHeader();
    let request_body = {
      'x-access-token':auth_header['x-access-token'],
      'user':user
    }
    return axios.post(API_URL + '/biodata/getbio', {request_body}, { timeout : API_CALL_TIMEOUT });
  }

}

export var biodata = new Biodata();
```

Helper Module

```js
export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';

export const API_CALL_TIMEOUT = 2000;// API call timeout in milliseconds

export function authHeader() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (user && user.accessToken) {
        return {'x-access-token':user.accessToken};
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

export function userState() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if(user){ 
        return {status:{loggedIn: true}, user};

    } else{ 
        return {status:{loggedIn: false}, user:null};
    }
}
```

Error on console

```
Cannot POST /biodata/getbio
```

Kindly help and advise should I mislooking on most important parts of this issues. Thanks.

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is:  `req.body.request_body` is undefined.  `console.log(req.body)` to see what's there

Comment: @Dan thanks buddy for first advise. will do this shortly to check on this first.

Comment: @Dan hey buddy, I try with POST method and results as per above updated questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of my try and error attempts, I found this due to my logic mistakes on backend router files. Here's the codes:-

```js
const authController = require("../controllers/auth.controller");
const bioController = require("../controllers/biodata.controller");

module.exports = function(app) {   
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //allowing headers for CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing). 

    //this is to allow frontend and backend to communicate with eachother.

    //this is literally the first thing we check before we call "next()" method on express 
    //and continue with the rest of the routing checks.

    //SUPER IMPORTANT

    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.get(
    "/biodata/infobio",
    [authController.verifyToken],
    bioController.infoBio
  );

  app.post(
    "/biodata/getbio",
    [authController.verifyToken],
    bioController.getBio
  );   

};
```

After found this issue as per this code:-

> app.post(
> "/biodata/getbio",
> [authController.verifyToken],
> bioController.getBio
> );
> I noticed that I use app.get instead of app.post that caused my request return error 404(Not found). I consider this case closed and apologize to all since I'm still learning on VueJS and axios.